# How can I get value? Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have this code in the xml view:

```xml
<field name="fueled" sum="Sum of fueled"/>
```

How can I get value sum attribute to do some calculating in python file?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
from lxml import etree

etree.fromstring('<field name="fueled" sum="Sum of fueled"/>').xpath('//field/@sum')[0]
```